# Impact of changing JVM vendor on you application

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot

If you want to change JVM(only vendor and stick to same version of JAVA) for your application, what aspects one should verify to make sure your application will perform optimally.

The differences between these JVMs which will have obvious impact on your application's performance & maintenance would be:

- Memory management & garbage collection algorithms
- Security & stability patches

So is it safe to assume that if your application performance tests results are good and if the security & stability patch support from the vendor is acceptable then you can go ahead with the change.

I am assuming that switching JVMs will not have any functional impact and impact will be only on performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `JVM` and `Java`(and implicitly `javac` compiler).

When you say change `vendor` you probably mean both: re-compile the `.java` files with the new compiler and running those generated `.class` files on the new `jvm` vendor.

In this case the `bytecode` might differ (content of .class file). *Generally* you don't care about that, because your code still runs fine. But it's good to know that is might change and you can't rely on that.

The problem with a different jvm is far bigger as far as I can tell. Each vendor might do their optimizations on it and it might differ quite a lot. *For example, your current* jvm might inline methods after 2000 calls, while your new jvm might do that after 10000 calls. So **JIT might differ**. It might use different Garbage Collector implementation and even might slice your memory differently than `Oracle Hotspot`, so **heap might differ**.

You might have tunning parameters enabled now (`-XX:SomeProp`) that simply will not be understood by your new vendor. Tools provided for debugging problems might also be different: **tools and start-up properties** are to be be watched for.

Then there are bugs. Even if all compilers must comply with `jls`, they all have bugs (it's still software) and while some things *would normally* compile/run now, they might suddenly break due to the change that you are making.

I don't know if there is **safe way** to change this. Because it depends on what you actually define as safe. If all you care about is that code runs, tests also and performance tests are OK - then you are fine.

As a last note: we were involved in such a move from `J9` to `Oracle Hotspot`. The change was not easy, mainly because `J9 AOT Compiler`, `heap memory j9 != oracle`, `different GC` (it was quite a while ago and I do not want to repeat that story).

Comment: Changing JVMs doesn't require recompiling the java source.  Java has very strong specifications and each compliant JVM should be able to run .class files compiled by any other JVM.